# Identifying feature values that influence an outcome

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a data set which has data about 1 million people. Data about each person consists of a 'Score' and about 100 features (each of which refers to some characteristic of the person - example - age, location, ethnicity, level of education, access to internet, etc. etc. )

I want to find the clusters/pockets within this population that have a very low 'Score. I also want to get the set of feature values that are representative of these clusters. An example output would be - (1) People with Location = X,Y,Z and Level of Education < A have low score AND (2) People with Level of Education = B and Location = C have low score AND (3).. so on.

What statistical analysis/ML method is best suited for this?

Comment: One thing to add - in my data set the score may not be linearly correlated with the features. For example, my data set could have very low average score for say people with Location = x, whereas it may not vary significantly for other Location values.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a variant of the [a priori algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) -- an algorithm that can automatically extract significant correlations from a database.  The main problem you will encounter is that it is usually formulated in terms of discrete variables (there may be extensions to continuous variables, but I'm unaware of them), so you may need to discretize your continuous variables.  The other aspect of customization is that you known that you care about low scores; the basic a priori algorithm doesn't favor some variables, so again you'll have to find an appropriate variant.